# Remove excess(duplicate) objects from a list of objects that are not exactly duplicates

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, foreach, duplicates

I have a list of objects in C# which have multiple properties (Price, color, description and dateAdded but **NOT** a unique ID). The final goal is to filter the list - if two of the objects have the same price and color, we check if the descriptions contain more than 50% matching words (but are not the same, as they are free entry). Also, sometimes the dateAdded can be empty, so preferably if there are 2 "duplicates" we keep the one **with** dateAdded.

So

1. [$100, Red, "beautiful cotton shirt", "10/29/2020"]

and

2. [$100, Red, "cotton shirt", "01/01/0001"]

are considered duplicates, and the one without date needs to be removed from the list.

I know a simple duplicate removal can be achieved with linq's

```
var noDups = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

but if I a perform a grouping in my case, i'm not sure how to check the description/date later.

Also, I'm aware this can be solved with multiple foreach loops and temporary lists, but I'm afraid it becomes too complex that way

What I tried is working with the same list - dynamically removing elements, but after both loops finish elements are missing.

```
foreach (var prop in listOfProducts)
            {
                foreach (var secondProp in listOfProducts.Where(x => x.ListingID != prop.ListingID).ToList())
                {
                    if (prop.Price == secondProp.Price && prop.Color == secondProp.Color )
                    {
                      
                        var propSplitDesc = prop.Description.Split().ToList();
                        var secondPropSplitDesc = secondProp.Description.Split().ToList();
                        var descLength = propSplitDesc.Count > secondPropSplitDesc.Count
                            ? propSplitDesc.Count
                            : secondPropSplitDesc.Count;
                        var wordsMatching = propSplitDesc.Intersect(secondPropSplitDesc).ToList();
                        if (wordsMatching.Count >= (double)descLength / 2)
                        {
                            finalProp.ComaprableProperties.Remove(prop.DateAdded == DateTime.MinValue
                              ? prop
                              : secondProp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there anything not too complex that can be done, or can linq be used somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I think the following should work for you. Then it's up to you if it's easier to read or not:

```cs
var noDups = myList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Color, x.Price })
    .SelectMany(group => 
    {
        var candidates = group.ToList();
        return candidates.Where(x => candidates
            .Where(y => y != x) // Don't compare against itself
            .All(y =>
                // Other candidate does not match by words
                !HasMoreThanHalfMatchingWords(x, y)
                // ... or this one does have a proper date
                || x.DateAdded != DateTime.MinValue));
    });

// In some other place...
bool HasMoreThanHalfMatchingWords(string desc1, string desc2)
{
    // Logic to compare if the strings contain more than 50% matching words
}
```

---

### Considerations about your definitions

I think you have a flaw in your definition of a "duplicate". Consider the following example:

**ItemA**

- Description: "the brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
- dateAdded: 10/29/2020

**ItemB**

- Description "the brown fox jumped"
- dateAdded: 10/29/2020

**ItemC**

- Description: "jumped over the lazy dog"
- dateAdded: 01/01/0001

Which items are considered duplicated and which ones will end up in the final list?

A and B share 50% of the words.
A and C do as well.

Should you keep only A even though B and C seems different, which means you're losing items that are not duplicated?

Should you keep both A and B? A because it has a "dateAdded" and is a duplicate of C, and B because, well... it's not a "duplicate" of C so you should keep one of them?

Comment: My example was a bit stupid, but in the real scenario I have there's a list where no more than 2 are similar. So, if there's a list of 50 objects, 10 of which are found twice (but with different description or/and dateAdded) i need the list after filtering to have 40. So the 10 "duplicates" removed and because those 10 are there twice - if possible the ones with no dateAdded should be gone. Ignore the condition checking the "duplication", what I mostly struggle with is creating the list. In the example you mentioned i'd remove both B and C, but such scenario won't happen (>2 similar)

Comment: @Filip5991 In my example there are also no more than 2 similar objects ;) But anyway... I've added an example which I believe should work for you. You'll have to test it though.